# Function with vector as argument in Octave

Tags: function, math, vector, octave

How can I make a function with a vector as input and a matrix as an output?

I have to write a function that will convert cubic meters to liters and English gallons. The input should be a vector containing volume values ​​in m ^ 3 to be converted. The result should be a matrix in which the first column contains the result in m ^ 3, the second liter, the third English gallon.

I tried this:

```
function [liter, gallon] = function1 (x=[a, b, c, d]);
  liter= a-10+d-c;
  gallon= b+15+c;
endfunction
```

Comment: What is the function supposed to do? What does the input look like? What should the output look like? What is the current problem with this code, does it result in errors, are the results incorrect, does it make your computer explode ...? Please [edit] the question with more details. See [ask] and [mcve] for details on how to ask a question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there.

The `x=[a,b,c,d]` part is superfluous, your argument should be just `x`.

```
function [liter, gallon] = function1 (x);
  a = x(1); b = x(2); c = x(3); d = x(4);
  liter  = a - 10 + d - c;
  gallon = b + 15 + c;
endfunction
```

If you want your code to be safe and guard against improper inputs, you can perform such checks manually inside the function, e.g.

```
assert( nargin < 1 || nargin > 4, "Wrong number of inputs supplied");
```

The syntax `x=[a,b,c,d]` does not apply to octave; this is reserved for setting up default arguments, in which case a, b, c, and d should be given specific values that you'd want as the defaults. if you had said something like `x = [1,2,3,4]`, then this would be fine, and it would mean that if you called the function without an argument, it would set `x` up to this default value.